# Showing maximum of a function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

Define $g,h:\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: ||x|| \leq 1\} \rightarrow \ \mathbb{R}^3$ by:
$$g(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}) $$
$$h(x,y)=(x,y,-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}) $$
Show that the maximum of $f$ on $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3: ||x||=1\}$ is either the maximum of $f\circ g$ or the maximum of $f \circ h$ on $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: ||x||\leq1\}$

My attempt:

I am not really sure how to start here except I know that:

If $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ then the max (or min) of $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ occurs at a point $a$ in the interior of $A$ and $D_if(a)=0$ (if it exists).

If we let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: ||x|| \leq 1\}$ then $int(A)=||x|| < 1$

Comment: You're making this too hard. Assuming $f$ is continuous, by the maximum value theorem it must have a maximum on the unit sphere $S=\{x:\|x\|=1\}$.  $g$ and $h$ give parametrizations of the two closed hemispheres, whose union is $S$. Now proceed.

Comment: You mean "$f g$ or $f h$ on $\{x\in R^2:\|x\|=1\}$" not "on $\{x\in R^3:\|x\|\leq1\}$".

Comment: @TedShifrin so the maximum must lie in either one of those 2 hemispheres which is f on g or f on h?

Comment: @user25466524: You misread the question.